# What is another name for this Dell puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification

I remember, when filling out variety puzzle books from Dell Publishing, there being one or two logic puzzles per book called "Eight Ball." I really like these puzzles, but I can find NO information on them anywhere! It was a deduction puzzle about putting groups of 8 numbers into a labyrinth shaped like a giant 8 ball. Some numbers were already filled in, <s>and each number group started and ended in 8</s>.

Is there another name for this puzzle? Or is there more information about it... anywhere? Somewhere I can play it without buying an entire book for *one puzzle*?

EDIT: Due to... particular design choices of the Dell-Penny website, I was able to find a copy:
[image: An incomplete 8-Ball puzzle]

Comment: Can you give a example? Maybe a picture?

Comment: It looks like you may be able to find this puzzle at this site: https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/free_puzzles/default.aspx if you look in the archives for 8/5/16 based off Amy Lowenstein's post here: https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/forum/topic1293-free-puzzles-of-the-day-vii.aspx (I would have looked for the specific puzzle, but it required me to sign up for the site and I didn't want to. :P)

Comment: Can you be more specific about the rules, maybe with a sketch if possible?

Comment: @phroureo The puzzle archives only go back a month. :(
I can't find any of my puzzle books right now, otherwise I'd throw in a picture. They were full-page puzzles, and drawing one would be too difficult/ time consuming. I'll buy a puzzlebook tomorrow and take a picture, if nobody can do without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first it sounded like you are describing Logic Art puzzles or [Nonorams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram). But those can be in any shape, not just and eight ball. 
[Sample here](https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/Upload/PuzzleFiles/Sample/lapw_p0411_samplepuz.pdf).

But it turns out what you are looking for is actually a proprietary PennyPress puzzle which doesn't have references anywhere else. I don't think there is any other generic name for this. It is just called "Eight Ball" and appears under the "Variety Puzzle" section.

Here is the only Eight Ball sample I was able to *ahem* "extract" with some deductive url finagling.
https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/Upload/PuzzleFiles/Daily/DellV/20160805_puz_dvar.pdf